# CSV export changing a boolean column from true/false to yes/no

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

When I export my CSV, I want to change a boolean column to read "Yes" or "No".

My CSV code is simple:

```
def to_csv(data)
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << DataPoint.data_point_columns
    data.all.each do |d|
      csv << d.attributes.values_at(*DataPoint.data_point_columns)
    end
  end
end

def data_point_columns
  ["id", "category", "subcategory", "percentage"]
end

data = [#<DataPoint:0x007fc77d1ffc60
id: 20,
category: "Cat 1",
subcategory: "Cat 2",
percentage: true
>,
#<DataPoint:0x007fc77d1ff878
id: 22,
category: "Cat 1",
subcategory: "Cat 2",
percentage: false
>]
```

I want the csv to look like this
[image: expected csv]

How can I do this if "percentage" is a boolean?

Comment: Please show a sample of your input data and what you want the output CSV to look like. That helps avoid guesses or people trying to write your specs for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by replacing

`d.attributes.values_at(*DataPoint.data_point_columns)`

with:

```
def to_csv(data)
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << DataPoint.data_point_columns
    data.all.each do |d|
      percentage = d.percentage ? "Yes" : "No"
      csv << [d.id, d.category, d.subcategory, percentage]
    end
  end
end

def data_point_columns
  ["id", "category", "subcategory", "percentage"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def data_point_columns
  ["id", "category", "subcategory", "percentage_to_true_false"]
end
```

in `DataPoint` model

```
def percentage_to_true_false
 case percentage
 when yes
   'true'
 when 'no'
   'false'
 end
```

You might have to modify how you load the CSV row.

Comment: I'm unsure how this works.  Where do I call the percentage_to_true_false method?